# MySQL wampserver database date format

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, wampserver

[image: heres my database]

how do i change the format in my database like this format 04-Oct-2016?

Comment: Do you want to store the value in that format? or retrieve date value in that format?

Comment: Do you want it in Java?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne i want to put 04-Oct-2016 format into database.

Comment: I don't think you can change the way you store in database. What you can do is change the format when you retrieving the date from your app

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne how can i do that? can you help me or explain it to me? Please

Comment: You can use date format function. Read on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: The DateTime datatype has the format it has so that MYSQL can use dates correctly (sort/find/between/timezone etc). Dont try and change it. If you want to present a date in any other format you do that in the presentation layer i.e. the PHP/HTML/JAVA etc So it also has to be saved in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` layout as well

Answer (score 0):

You can save the date into the table as DATETIME format and while retrieving back use the below query to format in a right way

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d/%b/%Y') datetime FROM table
```

or after you get the actual value you can convert to the format like

```
$php_timestamp_date = date("d F Y", $php_timestamp);
```

or

```
$php_timestamp_date = date("d F Y H:i:s", $php_timestamp);
```